# 1 - continue program, 0 - end program, how make

Tags: java

I want make my program continue or end, `1` - continue `0` - end, how can I make this?

I tried adding `System.exit(1)` and I don't know what I need to do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("first number: ");
        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("second number: ");
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Operation?: ");
        String operation = scanner.next();

        if (operation.equals("+")) {
            System.out.print("Answer: ");
            System.out.println(num1 + num2);

        } else if (operation.equals("-")) {
            System.out.print("Answer: ");
            System.out.println(num1 - num2);

        } else if (operation.equals("*")) {
            System.out.print("Answer: ");
            System.out.println(num1 * num2);

        } else if (operation.equals("/")) {
            System.out.print("Answer: ");
            System.out.println(num1 / num2);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error! ");
        }
        System.out.println("0-exit, 1-continue");
        int command = scanner.nextInt(); // how make this???
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a `while` loop which should finish when the user types `0`. This way, there's no need to use `System.exit(1)`, just let the program finish normally.

Comment: a `do {} while()` is likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int command = 0;

        try (var scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            do {

                System.out.println("first number: ");
                int num1 = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("second number: ");
                int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Operation?: ");
                String operation = scanner.next();

                System.out.print("Answer: ");
                switch (operation) {
                    case "+":
                        System.out.println(num1 + num2);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        System.out.println(num1 - num2);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        System.out.println(num1 * num2);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        System.out.println(num1 / num2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error! ");
                }

                System.out.println("0-exit, 1-continue");
                command = scanner.nextInt();

            } while (command == 1);
        }
    }
```

The program will exit (without calling System.exit()) as soon as the main() method completes (in given scenario).